# Drawing using drawRect: heavy for the performance?

Tags: iphone, performance, drawrect

I'm writing a mathematical app where the user can draw several mathematical figures like circles, squares, lines, etc... I'm drawing directly to the screen using the current graphics context, Quartz 2D, UIView and `drawRect:` method.

I'm not sure about what I'm asking, but is this drawing way using `drawRect:` every time heavy for the performance (iPhone battery)? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This question is not answerable because it depends entirely on what you are doing in drawRect.

Comment: it all depends on how often you update the screen (call `setNeedsDisplay`)

Comment: Yes, it depends on what you draw, but there's still something to say about this: Performance is - from my experience - not the problem with draw rect (the opposite is the case). But if you have a lot of view instances, that are all drawn with drawRect-implementations shown at the same time (or maybe off-screen on a scrollview) you'll get a memory problem, because there is a lot of optimization inside UIKit which can not be used by the framework if you draw yourself with core graphics. As always: Take you first approach, test it and only think about alternatives if tests fail.

Comment: Many thanks. Depending on what the user want to draw I create dynamically max 10 views every time in which the mathematical figures are drawn one after the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to profile your app's execution under heavy conditions using Instruments in order to answer your question. It may be heavy, or it may be fine. The complexity can vary greatly for a number of reasons. If the interface is visibly lagging/slow, that *may* indicate your drawing is taking too much time. If you suspect it will be an issue due to complexity, sample often in order to spot and correct issues as they are introduced.